# Open .lps file in textarea java

Tags: java, file, file-io, operating-system, file-format

I am trying to open .lps file in jtextarea but this file format may be not supported by textarea.
the output strings are not read able.

this file is output of .mcrl2 file you can check the further details at

http://www.mcrl2.org/release/user_manual/index.html

Suggest some way to open .lps file in jTextarea my OS is Windows .
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what is an lps file? it would help if you can provide some information about the program that creates it or the content of such a file

Comment: this file is output of .mcrl2 file you can check the details of at

http://www.mcrl2.org/release/user_manual/index.html